# Test Hangs at "Instantiating tests..." for 20 seconds using Gradle

Tags: gradle, quarkus, junit-jupiter

I am running a test using Gradle and it says "Instantiating tests..." for about 20 seconds before actually running the test. How can I avoid this?

[image: instantiating-tests]

I am using `Quarkus 2.2.3.Final`, and `gradle-7.2`.

My test class:

```
class OrganizationServiceImplTest {
    @Test
    void getAllOrganizations() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The Run Configuration shows the following run command:

```bash
:test --tests "com.doortodoor.services.impl.OrganizationServiceImplTest.getAllOrganizations"
```

Idea Log File shows as follows:

```
2022-11-09 21:56:29,387 [117677008]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2 
2022-11-09 21:56:29,387 [117677008]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-17.0.2 
2022-11-09 21:56:29,466 [117677087]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --init-script C:\Users\242924\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ijmapper.gradle --tests com.doortodoor.services.impl.OrganizationServiceImplTest.getAllOrganizations --init-script C:\Users\242924\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ijresolvers.gradle 
2022-11-09 21:56:30,284 [117677905]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appDaemonCodeAnalyzerSettings took 64 ms 
2022-11-09 21:56:30,381 [117678002]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=quarkus-quickstart-security, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\source\quarkus-quickstart-security)Encoding took 11 ms, RunManager took 36 ms
```

Solutions I have tried that didn't work include:

## Solution 1: Use Eclipse Compiler

[Why does IntelliJ take 20+ seconds to launch a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913201/why-does-intellij-take-20-seconds-to-launch-a-unit-test)
Compiler -> Java Compiler

- Use compiler: Eclipse
- Generate no warnings

Problem: It didn't improve the time.

## Solution 2: Use shared Spring Context

[Gradle is executing tests terribly slow because it is adding to much tests to the suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267670/gradle-is-executing-tests-terribly-slow-because-it-is-adding-to-much-tests-to-th)

Problem: I'm not annotating my tests with `@SpringBootTest` (or using Spring for that matter).

## Solution 3: Enable Eclipse features such as incremental compilation

[Intellij idea tests compilation takes too long (compared with Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141923/intellij-idea-tests-compilation-takes-too-long-compared-with-eclipse)

Comment: Could it be related to our Dev Services feature and that Quarkus is actually starting a Docker container for a database or any other service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anybody wondering, I was able to resolve the long hanging time by changing the test runner to IntelliJ Idea in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! That made a huge difference. Don't forget to *delete* your previous run configuration (which is still using Gradle) so that IntelliJ creates a new one using IntelliJ.